# Java/CSS - Vaadin: Add Switchbutton Background

Tags: java, vaadin

as first, sorry for my english

I want add a new background for my switch button, but it doesnt work. I had created a new rule in my style.css like this:

```
.v-switch-slider-gruppe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: url(images/GruppeSingle.png) no-repeat;
    width: 130px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

than I want to say with .addStyleName(..) use this css rule for the switch button

```
GridLayout grid = new GridLayout();
Switch sw = new Switch();
sw.addStyleName("v-switch-slider-gruppe" );
grid.addComponent( sw);
mainWindow.addComponent( grid );
```

but the compiler says this:

Dez 11, 2012 7:55:33 PM com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet      serveStaticResourcesInVAADIN
INFO: Requested resource [VAADIN/widgetsets/com.example.switchtest.widgetset.SwitchtestWidgetset/switch/images/GruppeSingle.png] not found from filesystem or through class loader. Add widgetset and/or theme JAR to your classpath or add files to WebContent/VAADIN folder.

Can anyone tell me, where is the mistake?

THX :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that styles.css is part of the WidgetSet, in the `com.example.switchtest.widgetset/public` directory, then the image GruppeSingle.png needs to be in relative to the same source location e.g. `com.example.switchtest.widgetset/public/images/GruppeSingle.png`